# Find the intersection between strings in 2 columns

Tags: r, string, intersection

I am trying to find the common words between 2 columns for each row in a data frame.
For example my input is:

```
C1                | C2
Roy goes to Japan | Roy goes to Australia 
I go to Japan     | You go to Japan
```

And I need a column appended as

```
C1                | C2                    | Result
Roy goes to Japan | Roy goes to Australia | Roy goes to
I go to Japan     | He goes to Japan      | to Japan
```

I tried `intersect` but it gives me intersection between C1 and C2, and not each element of C1 and C2. I guess I'll have to use something from `stringr` or `stringi` but not sure what. Also, my dataset is huge so something `fast` would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string on whitespace and then use `intersect` to find the common words.

```
df$result <- mapply(function(x, y) paste0(intersect(x, y), collapse = " "),
                    strsplit(df$C1, '\\s'), strsplit(df$C2, '\\s'))
df
#                 C1                    C2      result
#1 Roy goes to Japan Roy goes to Australia Roy goes to
#2     I go to Japan      He goes to Japan    to Japan
```

You could also do this with `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(result = map2_chr(str_split(C1, '\\s'), str_split(C2, '\\s'), 
                           ~str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse = " ")))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c("Roy goes to Japan", "I go to Japan"), 
    C2 = c("Roy goes to Australia", "He goes to Japan")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```